# Menu in System bar of Android 3.0

Tags: java, android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I would like to add a menu button in the System bar of Android 3.0, attached is a picture of the Firefox app on Android 3.0 which gives the system bar menu button and on clicking the button you see 4 options(Site Options, Preferences, Add-ons, Downloads). I would like to know how do I add this button(marked in red) in the system bar and also its corresponding options.

[image: (]

P.S: I have already tried adding the methods `nCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` and `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`, but these methods give me menu button in the action bar, which I dont' want.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> attached is a picture of the Firefox app on Android 3.0 which gives the system bar menu button and on clicking the button you see 4 options(Site Options, Preferences, Add-ons, Downloads)

That is because Firefox is not updated for Honeycomb. Once it is, their options menu will be in the action bar. Over time, all applications' options menus will be in the action bar. Options menus in the system bar are only for pre-Honeycomb apps.

Comment: so basically, I can't do it. Any way to overcome this?

Comment: My app is a Honeycomb app, I am developing an app in Xoom.

Comment: @Sana: Then please follow the platform convention and put your options menu in the action bar.

Comment: :-( ok! I wanted to avoid this, as the real estate on the screen was less and therefore I removed the Action Bar.

Comment: @Sana: The only apps that should remove the action bar are ones that do not have an options menu (e.g., some games).

Comment: Why not removing? Example, I have image viewer and want it display "fullscreen", as is usual also on PC. Menu button should in such case be on Status bar, which can't be hidden at all. Otherwise app has no Menu access, while there's plenty of space in status bar. I don't see reason to have action bar just to display one menu button.

Answer (score 4):

You only get the menu button if your app's declared targetSdkVersion and minSdkVersion are less than 11, which also means you're no longer writing a "honeycomb app." It's a compatibility feature.

Honeycomb tablet apps should display their menus in the action bar or elsewhere on-screen.